# Custom char device linux module under stock major (like "tty")

Tags: linux, driver

I'm writing my first linux kernel module. It is a standard char device to communicate over a GPIO pin.

It works like a charme. It is registered with its device name under /dev and in my own class name under /sys (it has some attributes available for configuration by the host application).

My wish is to move my device under **/dev/tty/** and **/sys/class/tty/** .

How should I change my below code to accomplish this?

Thank you very much!

```
  // Allocate major device number

  majorNumber = register_chrdev(0, DEVICE_NAME, &devFileOps);

  if (majorNumber < 0)
  {
    kobject_put(dev_kobj);

    pr_crit(
      "%s/%s: failed to register a major number.\n", 
      CLASS_NAME, 
      DEVICE_NAME
    );

    return majorNumber;
  }

  pr_debug(
    "%s/%s: successfully registered with major number %d.\n", 
    CLASS_NAME,
    DEVICE_NAME,
    majorNumber
  );

  // Register device class

  devClass = class_create(THIS_MODULE, CLASS_NAME);

  if (IS_ERR(devClass))
  {
    unregister_chrdev(majorNumber, CLASS_NAME); 
    kobject_put(dev_kobj);

    pr_crit(
      "%s/%s: failed to register device class.\n", 
      CLASS_NAME,
      DEVICE_NAME
    );

    return PTR_ERR(devClass);
  }

  pr_debug(
    "%s/%s: device class successfully registered.\n", 
    CLASS_NAME, 
    DEVICE_NAME
  );

  // Register device driver

  devDevice = device_create(
    devClass, 
    NULL, 
    MKDEV(majorNumber, 0), 
    NULL, 
    DEVICE_NAME
  );

  if (IS_ERR(devDevice))
  {
    class_destroy(devClass);
    unregister_chrdev(majorNumber, CLASS_NAME);
    kobject_put(dev_kobj);

    pr_crit("%s/%s: failed to create the device.\n", CLASS_NAME, DEVICE_NAME);

    return PTR_ERR(devDevice);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your device to be exposed as a TTY, implement it as a serial driver, similar to other devices in [`drivers/tty/serial`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/tty/serial). The kernel will apply [the TTY layer](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/serial/tty.txt) to it, and it will show up as a TTY.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can rename it to `/dev/tty` or any other class which is provided by an already loaded module.  Any attempt to load a module with an already existing class name will be rejected at the point of calling `class_create()`.

Any attempt to "chain on" another module to an existing will mess up the relationships of the `file_operations` entries for *owner*.

If you really wanted to do this and don't need the built in driver, you could configure a kernel that did not have the "conflicting" drivers installed and then name your module the same and install it.

Comment: However, building a kernel without the TTY device is… inadvisable. A lot of userspace software will fail to run on such a system.

Comment: @duskwuff:  Agreed.  However, it would be clear very quickly during boot up as to its feasibility.  It wouldn't be an obscure, hard to identify, latent error.